# MVC3 Razor - Foreach problems with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a foreach loop in my view that is not working correctly. My Model.AllSelectedQuestions is a type of List. So if Model.AllSelectedQuestions have 5 objects inside it will display 5 lines of . What I want to be able to do is to have a counter aswell that displays here is an example the boxes are the  links.

[image]

```
@{
    int nr = 1;
    foreach (SelectedQuestionViewModel items in Model.AllSelectedQuestions)
    {
        <a href="#" class="box" id="Question_(@items.QuestionID)"></a>
        <p>@nr++</p>
    }              
  }
```

The problem is that I get this result: nr++ nr++ nr++ nr++ nr++  when i have 5 objects in my list. But I want to get 1 2 3 4 5. Like the display example.

Any kind of help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: *What's wrong with your existing approach???*

Comment: you could try to wrap your anchor tag in an ordered list, it automatically generates the number sequence.

Comment: @Drew could give me an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe I'm wrong, but have You checked that code ?

```
<p>@(nr++)</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier, i think to just use an [ordered list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp) to handle the sequence.

```
<ol>
foreach (SelectedQuestionViewModel items in Model.AllSelectedQuestions)
{
    <li><a href="#" class="box" id="Question_(@items.QuestionID)"></a></li>
}
</ol>
```